# MySQL Amazon Aurora - a few slow queries causing extreme performance issues

Tags: mysql, query-performance, performance-tuning, aws-aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

I'm a dev, not a DBA, so pardon my ignorance.

I'm running on MySQL Amazon Aurora, single-instance (with a replica for failover).

A few days ago, my application had a handful of *extremely* slow queries (15min+) run simultaneously. I'm planning on optimizing those queries, but looking at the Aurora metrics for the `waits`, I'm curious about a couple of things. The spike from 18:30-19:00 is when the db was barely keeping up, slowing down the entire application.

- Is it normal for a handful of long-running queries to cause an extreme bottleneck across the db?
- Is there some way to terminate long-running queries after N number of seconds?
- Does the `wait/io/table/sql/handler` indicate that the db was busy running queries?

[image]

Comment: When you see very busy graphs and are connected, it would be a good idea to gather some SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; results to assist with identifying the contributors to the situation.  If Performance_Schema is ON, you may find details in the PS world.  SELECT @@performance_schema; will reveal current setting 0 = OFF and 1 = ON

Comment: Additional Aurora DB information request, please. 
Instance type? , any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide Aurora throttling suggestions.

Comment: When does Amazon do backups?

Comment: Get the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: Rick, For the When does Amazon do backups, this URL might be helpful.  https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=41&q=when+does+amazon+do+mysql+backups&cvid=c3a88c86c0664ec7b38d01224b3d1ed0&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQABhAMgYIAhAAGEAyBggDEAAYQDIGCAQQABhAMgYIBRAAGEAyBggGEAAYQDIGCAcQABhAMgYICBAAGEDSAQg4MjAwajBqMagCALACAA&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=U531

Answer (score -1):

Your 3 questions, answers

1. Yes
2. Yes  max_execution_time
3. Yes

View my profile.

Comment: Please refer to this URL for some details about your 2. question and response.    
https://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/finding-and-killing-long-running-mysql-queries/  Good luck, and let us know how well it works for you.